# How do I change the app launcher icon for a unity apk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I built an app for the play store and had chosen an app icon. I also the set app icons in unity. In the play store the icon I made shows but the app launcher icon on my device is just the unity logo. How do I fix this on my built unity apk?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open Unity and navigate to File > Build Settings. A window will open in that window at bottom left corner is a button "Player Settings", click on that to open another window. Here you can modify app icon.

[image]

Comment: Never mind. It takes google play a while to update the app launcher icons.