# Unity apk file installing 2 icons

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, icons, apk

The file apk install 2 icons. I doesn't know why it happen. I doesn't use Manifest file.
How I can resolve this?

Thanks.

I tested with a android manifest file. But the result is same.

Comment: What exactly do you mean 'apk file installing 2 icons'. Are you talking about the app icons?

Comment: @PavlosMavris exactly

Comment: You can check this answer right here on how to change the app icon, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295195/how-do-i-change-the-app-launcher-icon-for-a-unity-apk

Comment: You must post a [Minimal, Reproduciple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Apart from that, is this a coding/build question? Because if you are having problem with Android itself, you should look for help with their support.